# Box2D: Problems with LinearImpulse

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I have a problem with Box2D.
I tried to do LinearImpulse in render():

```
Player.body.applyLinearImpulse(0, -12, Player.body.getPosition().x, Player.body.getPosition().y, true);
```

But it doesn't work. Body stays on it position.

DynamicBody.

```
public static Body createBox(World world, BodyType type, float width, float height, float density)
{
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    def.type = type;
    Body box = world.createBody(def);

    PolygonShape poly = new PolygonShape();
    poly.setAsBox(width, height);

    box.createFixture(poly, density);
    poly.dispose();

    return box;
}

    body = MyWorld.createBox(world, BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1);
    body.setTransform(startX, startY, 0); 
    body.setFixedRotation(true);
```

LInearVelocity works good.

OK, I set very big value for impulse and it starts to work. But body moves only on ~1 meter (after Contacting with ther body). How can I make the body moves far?

Comment: OK, I set very big value for impulse and it starts to work. But body moves only on ~1 meter (after Contacting with ther body). How can I make the body moves far?

Comment: Do you use Box2D with everything scaled down? Because if you set Width and Height normally of an Box2D object weighs a whole lot. So you might need to set the mass accordingly. Or start working with scaled down physics.